# Java passing arrays into object issue

Tags: java, arrays, class, static

In java, how do you pass an array into a class. When ever I do I get a "Can not refrence a non-static variable in a static context". the array has 10 positions. I declared the array as.

edit: is this a clearer example? I should also make note that my teacher completely ignored what is static, and how it is used, claiming it isnt important for the programmer to understand.

**edit 2: I managed to get it to work by taking 
`sorter sort = new sorter();`
and turned it into 
`static sorter sort = new sorter();`
what exactly did this do to my program, is this considred a bad fix?**

main

```
public class example {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] test = new int[10];
     sorter sort = new sorter();

     sort.GetArray(test);


    }
}
```

class

```
public class sorter {

    int[] InputAR = new int[10];

    public sorter
    {

    }

        public void GetArray(int[] a)
    {


    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete to answer your question. *Looks like* your problem is that you're trying to access an instance variable from a static method, which is not possible.

Comment: Well the problem isn't in the code you've shown. It must be in the code you haven't shown. Please post a short but *complete* example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: `"Can not refrence a non-static varible in a static context"`---> says you are trying to use something which is non-static(instance variable) inside static methods.

Comment: Your teacher claims that static is not an important concept to understand ? Wow, what kind of teacher is this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't put enough code, put my guess is :

- You declared a non-static field (like int[] test = new int[10] instead of static int ...)
- the sort.getArray is in the main or in another static method.

This is not possible, because non static fields need a concrete object to exist.

Comment: where should. sort.getarray be?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are calling `sort.GetArray(test)` in some `static` method. You need to make your array variable `static` so as to access it.

Just read this [article](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) and you will understand the issue with your code.

Comment: @user1809295 Looking at your code, as you have declared array variable inside `main` its implicitly became an static variable, also as you declared the `sort` instance `static` too, it resolved your `Can not refrence a non-static varible in a static context` exception.

Answer (score 0):

"*Can not refrence a non-static varible in a static context*"

This error of yours has nothing to do with passing arrays or something.Somewhere in your code,or may be inside `public void GetArray(int[] a)` you a refering a `static` member but, with a non-static context.

Make that variable `non-static`, or the method `static`, or vice-versa.

Refer [This Link](http://www.javatutorialhub.com/java-static-variable-methods.html) for more info.